# looking at Apple's "Adventure Game" tutorial what does "in" mean?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

While looking at the source code for the tutorial adventure game using SpriteKit by Apple, I kept seeing variables being declared, and after they are declared there are open brackets, and the word "in".

This is the code I am using:

```
 let rightThumbstickHandler: GCControllerDirectionPadValueChangedHandler = { dpad, x, y in
        let length = hypotf(x, y)
        if length <= 0.5 {
            player.heroFaceLocation = nil
            return
        }
```

Like that, the "dpad, x, y in". Does anyone know what those are/what they are used for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a closure definition <s>which captures three variables</s> whose parameters are `dpad`, `x` and `y`. The `in` declares the actual beginning of the code which the closure executes. The values of the variables are provided by the caller.

**Update:** the `in` helps to mark the beginning of the code, i.e. suppose you have the following optional closure variable:

```
var foo : (Array<Int> -> Int)?
```

Now, you want to actually define this in your code and you want to achieve (pseudo-code):

```
foo = { for every int in array -> sum }
```

The question is, how do you access the array? And this is, when pattern matching jumps in, e.g.

```
foo = { numbers [...] }
```

Here, the array will be assigned to an immutable variable named `numbers`. After this you could write your code directly, but how do you want to distinct between variable assignments from the caller via pattern matching and local variables? And this is, when `in` comes into play, e.g. you would write

```
foo = { numbers in return numbers.reduce(0, { $0 + $1 }) }
```

Now, it is clear, that everything after `in` will be used inside the closure for computation. Furthermore, by having a look at the initial definition of the closure variable, you will also know, what type `numbers` will be.

For the sake of completeness, you can now call this by

```
let x = foo?([1, 2, 3]) // x = 6
```

Comment: What do you mean by it declares the actually beginning of the code? I understood the rest but that part, sorry:/

Comment: "This is a closure definition which captures three variables dpad, x and y." NO. These three variables are the parameters of the closure. That's the opposite of capturing.

Comment: By capturing, I was referring to the fact, that these variables are assigned by the caller. But I agree that there is a difference to capturing a variable outside the closure, so I'll revise my wording.

Answer (score 1):

This is a closure. it is basically structured like a function.

a function is

```
func ( dpad:Cgpoitn,x:cgfloat, y:cgfloat)->(void){
//code 
}
```

a closure is just structured differently.

```
{dpad,x,y in 
//the code
}
```

go to a 34 min 00 and watch the next 2 minutes and closures are explained well
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLJtT7eSykg
-- paul hegarty : developing iOS apps with swift available on iTunes U
- he is awesome